# Kotlin Can't transfer data from Response to RecyclerView using retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I'm trying to make a currency app I can get info from the API but can't transfer the data from response to RecyclerView. When I try to change the cryptoModels to arraylist of response.body it crashes the app and giving 3 errors in RecyclerAdapter. I have tried many different variations of coding but nothing seems to work. My recyclerview doesn't get the info from API but when I try to check Response it contains the info I need.

Here is my MainActivity

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerAdapter.Listener{

    private val BASE_URL = "https://v6.*******-api.com/**/"
    private var cryptoModels : ArrayList<CryptoModel>? = null
    private var cryptoName : CryptoModel? = null
    private var recyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // RecyclerView

        val layoutManager : RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        loadData()

    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(CryptoAPI::class.java)
        val call = service.getData()


        call.enqueue (object : Callback<CryptoModel> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CryptoModel>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<CryptoModel>,
                response: Response<CryptoModel>,

            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    response.body()?.let {
                      cryptoModels.let {
                          if(it!= null) {
                              recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(it!!, this@MainActivity)
                              binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
                          }

                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onItemClick(cryptoModel: CryptoModel) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked : + ${cryptoModel.conversion_rates}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

here is my RecyclerAdapter

```
 class RecyclerAdapter(private val cryptoList : ArrayList<CryptoModel>, private val listener 
 : Listener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RowHolder>() {

    private val colors : Array<String> = 
    arrayOf("#FFFFFF","#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#008000","#00FFFF")

    interface Listener {
        fun onItemClick(cryptoModel: CryptoModel)
    }

    class RowHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        private lateinit var binding : RecyclerRowMainBinding

        fun bind(cryptoModel : CryptoModel, colors : Array<String>, position: Int, listener : 
    Listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(cryptoModel)
            }
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[position %6]))
            binding.currencyName.text = cryptoModel.base_code
            binding.currencyPrice.text = cryptoModel.conversion_rates.toString()
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RowHolder {
        val view = 
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_main,parent,false)
        return RowHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RowHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(cryptoList[position],colors,position,listener)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cryptoList.size
    }
 }
```

and my CryptoModel

```
 data class CryptoModel(
   
    val conversion_rates : Map<String,Double> ,
    val base_code : String ,)
```

and my CryptoAPI

```
interface CryptoAPI {

    @GET("ea37f798********adf1/latest/USD")
    fun getData()  : Call<CryptoModel>



}
```

Recycler Row xml codes

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currency_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currency_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly my recyclerview xml codes

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: My API looks like this]

Comment: Not sure I can help right now, but if you could post the errors as well that might pinpoint the issue better.

Comment: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized  its the binding in the RecyclerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code works after some changes first of all binding in the RecyclerAdapter doesn't work so I've changed it like this

```
    package com.example.retrofitcrypto.adapter

import android.graphics.Color

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.R
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.model.CryptoConverterModel



class RecyclerAdapter(private val cryptoList : ArrayList<CryptoConverterModel>, private val listener : Listener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RowHolder>() {



    private val colors : Array<String> = arrayOf("#FFFFFF","#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#008000","#00FFFF")

    interface Listener {
        fun onItemClick(cryptoConverterModel: CryptoConverterModel)
    }

     class RowHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

         val currencyName : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.currencyName)
         val currencyPrice : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.currencyPrice)



        fun bind(cryptoConverterModel: CryptoConverterModel, colors : Array<String>, position: Int, listener : Listener) {

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(cryptoConverterModel)
            }
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[position %6]))
            currencyName.setText(cryptoConverterModel.cryptoName)
            currencyPrice.setText(cryptoConverterModel.cryptoRate.toString())


        }



     }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RowHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_main,parent,false)
        return RowHolder(view)
    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RowHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.bind(cryptoList[position],colors,position,listener)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cryptoList.size
    }



}
```

Also I've added a new class to break the conversiton_rates Map<String, Double> into two seperate pieces

```
   class CryptoConverterModel {
    var cryptoName : String? = null
    var cryptoRate : Double? = null
}
```

And finally I've changed MainActivity codes like this

```
   package com.example.retrofitcrypto.view

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.adapter.RecyclerAdapter
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.model.CryptoConverterModel
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.model.CryptoModel
import com.example.retrofitcrypto.service.CryptoAPI
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerAdapter.Listener{

    private val BASE_URL = "BASE_URL"
    private var recyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // RecyclerView

        val layoutManager : RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(CryptoAPI::class.java)
        val call = service.getData()


        call.enqueue (object : Callback<CryptoModel> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CryptoModel>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<CryptoModel>,
                response: Response<CryptoModel>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val cryptoArrayRates = ArrayList<CryptoConverterModel>()
                    response.body().let {
                        it?.conversion_rates?.forEach{
                            var crptoConverterModel = CryptoConverterModel()
                            crptoConverterModel.cryptoName = it.key
                            crptoConverterModel.cryptoRate = it.value
                            cryptoArrayRates.add(crptoConverterModel)

                        }
                        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(cryptoArrayRates,this@MainActivity)
                        binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
                    }



                    }
                }

        })
    }

    override fun onItemClick(crptoConverterModel: CryptoConverterModel) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked : + ${crptoConverterModel.cryptoName}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

The App works fine now thanks for all the help gioravered

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewHolder (RawHolder) is not initializing the binding variable.
You need to inflate your layout using DataBindingUtil in order to have a binding reference:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RowHolder {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        R.layout.recycler_row_main,
        parent,
        false)
    return RawHolder(binding)
}
```

Then, pass it to your RawHolder class.

```kotlin
class RowHolder(
    binding: RecyclerRowMainBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(
        cryptoModel : CryptoModel, 
        colors : Array<String>, 
        position: Int, 
        listener : Listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(cryptoModel)
            }
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[position %6]))
            binding.currencyName.text = cryptoModel.base_code
            binding.currencyPrice.text = cryptoModel.conversion_rates.toString()
        }
    }
```

This code is just to give an idea about the solution, adjust it to your needs..

Comment: val binding = RecyclerRowMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),R.layout.recycler_row_main,parent,false) Instead of using DataBindingUtil I used RecyclerRowMainBinding but there is still an error in the inflate part and when I try to use DataBindingUtil not enough information to infer type variable T sorry I'm still a noob in coding

Comment: Check the updated code. What error do you see?

Comment: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied inflate(LayoutInflater) defined in com.example.retrofitcrypto inflate(Layoutinflater,ViewGroup?,Boolean) defined in com.example.retrofitcrypto.databinding.RecyclerRowMainBinding

Comment: Can you add the entire Row xml to the question?

Comment: That is my entire row xml file

Comment: You need to wrap the entire layout inside <layout></layout> tags in order to be able to use binding for this layout.

Comment: Your code didnt work out for me I guess my main problem was having a Map<Sting, Double> in the code. NEvertheless Thank you for your help

Comment: In your answer, you completely changed the RawAdapter (removed the binding) so the original issue (binding == null) is (of course..) gone. Glad you've worked this out.